# avrdude: invalid output file format: -1

Tags: avrdude

I need to read the flash of an atmega8 chip. I program the chip with a working program, verification passes. Then I try to read the chip contents with the command below, and the read fails.

```
vorac@laptop:~/recorded$ sudo avrdude -p atmega8 -c usbasp -U flash:r:flash-image

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9307
avrdude: reading flash memory:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 2.32s

avrdude: writing output file "flash-mage"
avrdude: error opening flash-mage: No such file or directory
avrdude: output file flash-mage auto detected as invalid format
avrdude: invalid output file format: -1
avrdude: write to file 'flash-mage' failed

avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:FF, E:DD, L:E4)

avrdude done.  Thank you.

vorac@laptop:~/recorded$ ll flash-image 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 ное  5 10:29 flash-image
```

What is wrong? Something with permissions on my Ubuntu box? The file `flash-image` does not exist before running `avrdude`. I tried adding suffixes `.bin` and even `.hex` to `flash-image`, but the error is still there.

Also, no chip locking is programmed.

```
    # Default for the atmega8 is lfuse:E1, hfuse:D9
    # Low fuse for 8MHz clock: E4
    # High fuse with 512 bytes bootloader, start at application start: DD
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-U memtype:op:filename[:format]
```

Writing the flash memory does not require specifying the last field, because `avrdude` can detect it from the input file. However, for reading, there is not input file, so the format must be specified. For example, my command above becomes

```
sudo avrdude -p atmega8 -c usbasp -U flash:r:flash-image:r
```

for a raw binary. Silly question indeed, but as the error was un-ggolable, this answer could save someone 1 minute of their lives.